# How can I add specific keys from a dictionary to a list?

Tags: python, biopython

I want to build a code that splits a DNA sequence in its codon triplets and store them in a list, than use these strings find the relative frequency of these codons within the human organism. Finally the programm should arrange the codon triplets with the according frequency in an array. So far the program is working.
Now I want to add a third element to the array, and that is the amino acid the triplet encodes. In my dictionary, that are the keys.
Is there a proper way to get this specific keys used for the generation of the codon_value list out of the same dictonary or do I need to open up a second dictionary with the codons as keys and the respective amino acid as value?

This is the working part of the program:

```
dna_sequence = "GAGCGTCTGCTCCGTGTATAAGCCACGTCGGAGCT"
codons = [dna_sequence[i:i+3] for i in range (0, len(dna_sequence), 3)]

print("codons")
print(codons)


genetic_code = {
    "A": {"GCG" :33,"GCA" :23,"GCT" :18,"GCC" :26},       
    "R": {"AGG" :3,"AGA" :6, "CGG" :30, "CGA" :6,"CGT" :28,"CGC" :28},
    "N": {"AAT" :50,"AAC" :50},
    "D": {"GAT" :63, "GAC":27},
    "C": {"TGT" :46,"TGC" :54},
    "*": {"TGA" :25,"TAG" :25,"TAA" :50}, # * Stop codon
    "Q": {"CAG" :65,"CAA" :35},
    "E": {"GAG" :33,"GAA" :67},
    "G": {"GGG" :15,"GGA" :15,"GGT" :35,"GGC" :36},
    "H": {"CAT" :60,"CAC" :40},
    "I": {"ATA" :11,"ATT" :50,"ATC" :39},
    "L": {"TTG" :13,"TTA" :14,"CTG" :48,"CTA" :4,"CTT" :12,"CTC" :10},
    "K": {"AAG" :24,"AAA" :76},
    "M": {"ATG" :100}, # Start codon
    "F": {"TTT" :58,"TTC" :42},
    "P": {"CCG" :50,"CCA" :21,"CCT" :17,"CCC" :12},
    "S": {"AGT" :16,"AGC" :24,"TCG" :15,"TCA" :15,"TCT" :16,"TCC" :15},
    "T": {"ACG" :25,"ACA" :16,"ACT" :19,"ACC" :40},
    "W": {"TGG" :100},
    "Y": {"TAT" :59,"TAC" :41},
    "V": {"GTG" :35,"GTA" :17,"GTT" :28,"GTC" :20}
     }

codonValue = []

for codon in codons:
    for AS in genetic_code:
        if codon in genetic_code[AS]:
            codonValue.append(genetic_code[AS][codon]) 

print("codonValue")
print(codonValue)


CodonArray = list(zip(codons, codonValue))

print("CodonArray")
print(CodonArray)
```

```
Output:
codons
['GAG', 'CGT', 'CTG', 'CTC', 'CGT', 'GTA', 'TAA', 'GCC', 'ACG', 'TCG', 'GAG', 'CT']
codonValue
[33, 28, 48, 10, 28, 17, 50, 26, 25, 15, 33]
CodonArray
[('GAG', 33), ('CGT', 28), ('CTG', 48), ('CTC', 10), ('CGT', 28), ('GTA', 17), ('TAA', 50), ('GCC', 26), ('ACG', 25), ('TCG', 15), ('GAG', 33)]
```

And in this program I tried to integrate the amino acids within the CodonArray:

```
dna_sequence = "GAGCGTCTGCTCCGTGTATAAGCCACGTCGGAGCT"
codons = [dna_sequence[i:i+3] for i in range (0, len(dna_sequence), 3)]

print("codons")
print(codons)


genetic_code = {
    "A": {"GCG" :33,"GCA" :23,"GCT" :18,"GCC" :26},        
    "R": {"AGG" :3,"AGA" :6, "CGG" :30, "CGA" :6,"CGT" :28,"CGC" :28},
    "N": {"AAT" :50,"AAC" :50},
    "D": {"GAT" :63, "GAC":27},
    "C": {"TGT" :46,"TGC" :54},
    "*": {"TGA" :25,"TAG" :25,"TAA" :50}, # * Stop codon
    "Q": {"CAG" :65,"CAA" :35},
    "E": {"GAG" :33,"GAA" :67},
    "G": {"GGG" :15,"GGA" :15,"GGT" :35,"GGC" :36},
    "H": {"CAT" :60,"CAC" :40},
    "I": {"ATA" :11,"ATT" :50,"ATC" :39},
    "L": {"TTG" :13,"TTA" :14,"CTG" :48,"CTA" :4,"CTT" :12,"CTC" :10},
    "K": {"AAG" :24,"AAA" :76},
    "M": {"ATG" :100}, # Start codon
    "F": {"TTT" :58,"TTC" :42},
    "P": {"CCG" :50,"CCA" :21,"CCT" :17,"CCC" :12},
    "S": {"AGT" :16,"AGC" :24,"TCG" :15,"TCA" :15,"TCT" :16,"TCC" :15},
    "T": {"ACG" :25,"ACA" :16,"ACT" :19,"ACC" :40},
    "W": {"TGG" :100},
    "Y": {"TAT" :59,"TAC" :41},
    "V": {"GTG" :35,"GTA" :17,"GTT" :28,"GTC" :20}
     }

#genetic_code["A"] -> spuckt zeile aus
#genetic_code["A"]["GCG"]: spuckt 33 aus

codonValue = []     #empty list codon value
ASseq = []          #empty list aminoacid sequence

for codon in codons:
    for AS in genetic_code:
        if codon in genetic_code[AS]:
            codonValue.append(genetic_code[AS][codon])    

for codon in codons:         
    if codon in genetic_code[AS]:
        ASseq.append(genetic_code.keys())


print("codonValue")
print(codonValue)
print("ASseq")
print(ASseq)

CodonArray = list(zip(codons, codonValue, ASseq))

print("CodonArray")
print(CodonArray)
```

Obviously, that didn't work.

```
codons
['GAG', 'CGT', 'CTG', 'CTC', 'CGT', 'GTA', 'TAA', 'GCC', 'ACG', 'TCG', 'GAG', 'CT']
codonValue
[33, 28, 48, 10, 28, 17, 50, 26, 25, 15, 33]
ASseq
[dict_keys(['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', '*', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V'])]
CodonArray
[('GAG', 33, dict_keys(['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', '*', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']))]
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What exactly is the output you expected? It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It should look like this:
CodonArray
[('GAG', 33, "E"), ('CGT', 28, "R"), ('CTG', 48, "L"), etc. 
So the key "E", which stores the codons GAG and GAA, should be displayed at the third position

Comment: When I use`list(*ASseq)` ' it looks much better, but the keys displayed in the array are not the ones in which the codons are stored that were used to get the codonValue

Comment: Output looks like this: `CodonArray
[('GAG', 33, 'A'), ('CGT', 28, 'R'), ('CTG', 48, 'N'), ('CTC', 10, 'D'), ('CGT', 28, 'C'), ('GTA', 17, '*'),` which is the very same order of the keys in the list. For GAG, there should be an "E"

Comment: I posted my comment before you showed the desired result, so I deleted it since I realized it wasn't what you wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

In `if codon in genetic_code[AS]:`, the variable `AS` is out of scope because its value is not updated inside this loop, the problem is that you are always checking against the last value of AS from the previous loop.

Lets try to update the amino acid in the first loop when you are appending the codon value

```
dna_sequence = "GAGCGTCTGCTCCGTGTATAAGCCACGTCGGAGCT"
codons = [dna_sequence[i:i+3] for i in range (0, len(dna_sequence), 3)]

print("codons")
print(codons)

genetic_code = {
    "A": {"GCG" :33,"GCA" :23,"GCT" :18,"GCC" :26},        
    "R": {"AGG" :3,"AGA" :6, "CGG" :30, "CGA" :6,"CGT" :28,"CGC" :28},
    "N": {"AAT" :50,"AAC" :50},
    "D": {"GAT" :63, "GAC":27},
    "C": {"TGT" :46,"TGC" :54},
    "*": {"TGA" :25,"TAG" :25,"TAA" :50}, # * Stop codon
    "Q": {"CAG" :65,"CAA" :35},
    "E": {"GAG" :33,"GAA" :67},
    "G": {"GGG" :15,"GGA" :15,"GGT" :35,"GGC" :36},
    "H": {"CAT" :60,"CAC" :40},
    "I": {"ATA" :11,"ATT" :50,"ATC" :39},
    "L": {"TTG" :13,"TTA" :14,"CTG" :48,"CTA" :4,"CTT" :12,"CTC" :10},
    "K": {"AAG" :24,"AAA" :76},
    "M": {"ATG" :100}, # Start codon
    "F": {"TTT" :58,"TTC" :42},
    "P": {"CCG" :50,"CCA" :21,"CCT" :17,"CCC" :12},
    "S": {"AGT" :16,"AGC" :24,"TCG" :15,"TCA" :15,"TCT" :16,"TCC" :15},
    "T": {"ACG" :25,"ACA" :16,"ACT" :19,"ACC" :40},
    "W": {"TGG" :100},
    "Y": {"TAT" :59,"TAC" :41},
    "V": {"GTG" :35,"GTA" :17,"GTT" :28,"GTC" :20}
     }

codonValue = []     #empty list codon value
ASseq = []          #empty list aminoacid sequence

for codon in codons:
    for AS in genetic_code:
        if codon in genetic_code[AS]:
            codonValue.append(genetic_code[AS][codon])  
            ASseq.append(AS)  # append the amino acid to ASseq

print("codonValue")
print(codonValue)
print("ASseq")
print(ASseq)

CodonArray = list(zip(codons, codonValue, ASseq))

print("CodonArray")
print(CodonArray)
```

Comment: You welcome :)) dont forget to validate the answer if it fixed your problem.